# Custom Wordpress Tag Cloud

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm pretty new to Wordpress and I need your help.

I use WP-Polls plugin and I want to build a tag cloud for it. It would show most popular polls. I'm wondering how I can do that. I've tried creating my own taxonomy but with no luck. I'm not sure if I understand it correctly but Wordpress allows to create taxonomies for wp_posts table only. Is it correct?

Do you have any idea how I could solve the problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using [wp_generate_tag_cloud](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_tag_cloud). I have created a plugin that retrieves all the info from db and pass it to the above mentioned function.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about how to actually use that function to do it?